# Upload a Microsoft Access Database into a Microsoft SQL Server Express Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I am trying to upload a Microsoft Access Database into a Microsoft SQL Server Express Database.

The structure of the Access and the SQL Database are identical except for the name of the Primary Key.

Error Code:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No data exists for the row/column. at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.DoValueCheck(Int32 ordinal) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.GetValue(Int32 ordinal) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.get_Item(Int32 index) at ACCESStoMDF._Default.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\path2ACCESStoMDF\ACCESStoMDF\Default.aspx.cs:line 44
```

web.config

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ACCESSdb"
     connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\path1\DBaccess.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;" />
    <add name="MSSQLdb"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\MSSQLdb.mdf;User Instance=true;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

MSAccessTOMSSQL.aspx.cs

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ACCESSdb"].ConnectionString;
        String cmdStr = "SELECT * FROM [TableACCESS];";
        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdStr, conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {

                        String connStr1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MSSQLdb"].ConnectionString;
                        String cmdStr1 = "INSERT INTO [Table1] (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (@col1,@col2,@col3);";
                        try
                        {
                            using (SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(connStr1))
                            {
                                using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(cmdStr1, conn1))
                                {
                                    conn1.Open();
                                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col1", dr[1]);
                                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col2", dr[2]);
                                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col3", dr[3]);
                                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    conn1.Close();
                                    cmd1.Dispose();
                                    conn1.Dispose();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Label2.Text = "Insert Into: " + ex.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    conn.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label2.Text = "Access: " + ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `OleDbDataReader` allows you to process the results of a SELECT query row-by-row. As shown in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), you need to do something like

```csharp
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString());
}
reader.Close();
```

Note also that the numeric index of the returned row is zero-based, so the first column is `reader[0]`.